# Android button onTouch method working but not onClick

Tags: android, onclicklistener

The following is the code excerpt for my button.

```
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn_splash);
login.setTypeface(english);     
login.setOnClickListener(new SplashLoginListener());
login.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("touch", "touch");
            return false;
        }
});
```

The following is the code for the `SplashLoginListener` inner class.

```
private class SplashLoginListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("login", "login clicked");
        String uname = username.getText().toString().trim();
        String pword = Utils.Encryption.hashPassword(password.getText()
                .toString().trim());            
        UserLoginTask task = new UserLoginTask();
        task.execute(uname, pword);
    }

}
```

The `onTouch` method gets called. `onClick` doesn't. What might be wrong?

Comment: Do you not see the log in logcat `Log.d("login", "login clicked");`??

Comment: Must be sure that it is imported as a **import android.view.View.OnClickListener;**

Comment: share your xml layout part of button for this button

Comment: your code working perfectly. Can you show your full Activity class??

Answer (score 2):

Create your `Listener` as below...

```
private OnClickListener splashLoginListener = new View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("login", "login clicked");
        String uname = username.getText().toString().trim();
        String pword = Utils.Encryption.hashPassword(password.getText()
                .toString().trim());            
        UserLoginTask task = new UserLoginTask();
        task.execute(uname, pword);
    }

}
```

Then call the `Listener` as follows...

```
    login.setOnClickListener(splashLoginListener);
```